# What are the new appearances for squad members that comes with From Ashes?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The main menu shows me a "Additional content available" message and in the teaser text for From Ashes, it says it includes "A new appearance for each squad member!"

What are the new appearances for each squad member (pictures), and what bonus do they provide? Are they unlocked immediately if I get the DLC?

Comment: To be clear, you mean new appearance as in new outfit, right?

Comment: @MBraedley yeah, I mean the outfits, though they're "appearances" in the game's terminology

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To switch between them, as well as other alternate appearances, unlocked from, for instance, the Collectors Edition, and future DLC, use the **Cycle Appearance** button that appears at the bottom of the squad selection screen, as seen here:

[image]

Here's a terrible quality screenshot of everyone but EDI.

[image: Alts]

Source: http://www.gamersbook.com/scene/news/mass-effect-3-from-ashes-dlc-alternate-appearances

And here's the alt appearance for EDI since it's not in that screenshot.

[image]

As for the bonuses provided, here's most of the list, I could use some help with Kaidan.

**Garrus**: +25% Weapon Damage
**EDI**: +25% Shields
**Liara**: +25% Power Recharge Speed
**James**: +25% Weapon Damage
**Ashley**: +25% Weapon Damage
**Kaidan**: +25% Shields
**Tali**: +25% Weapon Damage

Comment: If someone comes along and confirms that that's CE EDI instead of From Ashes EDI, I'll switch up the screenshot. The other alt appearance is a black catsuit.

Comment: They do provide bonuses. Click on info in the character select screen and you'll see their armor bonus.

Comment: So they do! For some reason I did not think that was linked to appearance, as several of the appearances share the same bonus. Going through and editing.

Comment: Oh wow... I wondered where that awful costume of James came from. It's like I was punished for buying the DLC!

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I can 100% confirm that the EDI costume above is not from the CE.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: Kaidan's gives +25% Shields.